# what is difference between get or find in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2, cakephp-3.1

What is difference b/w get or find in **cakephp 3**.   Why we use get or find in **cakephp 3** .

Answer (score 1):

When you use `find()` method then you can pass condition as you want for retrieving data after filtering from db source. `find('first')` or `find('all')->first()` is behaving same.

**BUT**

`get($id)` is only apply condition on primary key field of table. It means give result for one record only due to condition on primary key.

When use `get()` method, if record is not found from db source then CakePHP throws NOT Found Exception. So this is very useful when give response as NOT FOUND - 404 For example Profile page, Blog detail page..etc

Answer (score 0):

**Get** is generally used for getting  a single entity by primary key .

```html
$this->Models->get($id);//here $id is your tables primary key
```

In **find**   we fine the data .

```html
$this->Models->find('all');//get all the data 

$this->Models->find('all')->first(); //get the first row
```

It can be used to find both the all data as well as first data .
Here we can also put conditions

Follow this link for more info

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Comment: also worth noting that get throws an exception if the operation does not find any result

Comment: @arilia yes we have to catch this exception

Answer (score 0):

You can call `find()` on table instance which constructs Query object and  returns it and you can continue chaining other methods like `where()` , `->select()`  and Query objects are lazy, and will not be executed unless you call `all()` , `toArray()` , `first()` , `firstOrFail()` etc , more explanation here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Whereas `get($primaryKey, $options = [])` will return record if found or throws not found exception if no record, it internally constructs query and calls `firstOrFail()`